# Trouble with BackgroundWorker and blocking operation

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Im writing a TFTP server application by using WPF of C#. I create a toggle button to start and stop a server. I use Backgroundworker class to send cancel sign immediately in order to prevent the UI hangs while transferring file. The problem is when I click Button to start server and then click again to stop it. The code breaks and give me an exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>     HResult=0x80004005
>     Message=A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
>     Source=System
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, EndPoint& remoteEP)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Receive(IPEndPoint& remoteEP)
>      at TftpServerApp.Code.TftpServer.StartTftpServices(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in D:\DA Mang\Do an TFTP\TftpServerApp\TftpServerApp\Code\TftpServer.cs:line 52
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>      at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:

> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveFrom(byte[], int, int, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, ref System.Net.EndPoint)
>       System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.Receive(ref System.Net.IPEndPoint)
>       TftpServerApp.Code.TftpServer.StartTftpServices(object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) in TftpServer.cs
>       System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
>       System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(object)

...and the code that throws exception:

```
while (true)
            {
                if (worker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    tftpServer.Close();
                    break;
                }
                int packetNr = 0;
                recBuffer = tftpServer.Receive(ref iep);/**Exception thrown here**/
                if (((Opcode)recBuffer[1]) == Opcode.READ_REQUEST)
                {.....
```

How can I handle in this situation?

Comment: If you're writing new code you really should be using `Task` and `CancellationToken` instead of the very outdated `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: I will try, but does it assure that trouble wont happen again?

Comment: @Herohtar perhaps, but that's not a compelling reason.  If OP is to [execute synchronous code on a background thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-1.html)  (which he is) then it is ok. If he's new to threading it's even more OK.  However, the OP is also using a _dedicated thread_ for I/O which **isn't** particularly `efficient`.  In this case, _I/O completion ports_ (IOCP) would make for a more efficient use of threads and the easiest way to do that is `async/await` with async forms of TCP APIs.  Just using `Task` isn't enough

Comment: @MickyD My statement wasn't meant to be a compelling reason in and of itself, but there are many compelling reasons to use `Task`, even just to run synchronous code on the thread pool.

Comment: Indeed, but just because something is _old_, doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't have a usecase.  People say similar things with regards to _.NET Remoting_ and say _WCF_. ;)